# Error al escribir en un archivo con python

Tags: python

Intento escribir el resultado de una función a un file en python.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
def grocer_item():
    file = open('InputFile.txt', 'r')
    d = dict()
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.lower()
        words = line.split(" ")
        for word in words:
            if word in d:
                d[word] = d[word] + 1
            else:
                d[word] = 1
    for key in list(d.keys()):
        print(key, ":", d[key])
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

> ```
> spinach : 5
> radishes : 3
> broccoli : 7
> peas : 8
> cranberries : 10
> potatoes : 5
> cucumbers : 9
> peaches : 5
> zucchini : 10
> cantaloupe : 2
> beets : 3
> cauliflower : 6
> onions : 4
> yams : 5
> apples : 4
> celery : 6
> limes : 1
> garlic : 8
> pumpkins : 2
> pears : 1
> ```

---

He tratado de escribir ese resultado en un file.

```
output = grocer_item
file2 = open('frequeny.dat', 'w')
file2.write(output)
```

Pero me dice que no puedo utilizar la función.

Comment: Pofrias poner el error exacto que te da?

Comment: Message=write() argument must be str, not function
  Source=C:\Users\la_di\source\repos\PythonApplication2\PythonApplication2\PythonApplication2.py
  StackTrace:
  File "C:\Users\la_di\source\repos\PythonApplication2\PythonApplication2\PythonApplication2.py", line 19, in <module> (Current frame)
    file2.write(output)

Comment: Edita tu pregunta añadiendo eso

Comment: Deves de convertir a string todo lo que vayas a escribir en el archivo, no puedes poner una lista así nomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La línea

```
output = grocer_item
```

asigna a la variable `output` la función `grocer_item`. No el resultado de la función, si no la función misma, su código.

Si quieres el resultado de la función, debes pasar sus argumentos entre paréntesis:

```
output = grocer_item()
```

Pero la función `grocer_item` no retorna nada. Lo útil sería que retornara un diccionario con las ocurrencias, por lo que la reescribimos así:

```
def grocer_item():
    file = open('InputFile.txt', 'r')
    d = dict()
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.lower()
        words = line.split(" ")
        for word in words:
            if word in d:
                d[word] = d[word] + 1
            else:
                d[word] = 1
    return d;
```

Ahora la podemos usar para obtener un diccionario, el que podemos imprimir o grabar en un archivo:

```
with open('frequeny.dat', 'w') as file2:
    d = grocer_item()
    for key in list(d.keys()):
        file2.write(f"{key} : {d[key]}\n")
```

Entonces, llamando a `grocer_item()` obtenemos un diccionario de ocurrencias. Con el `for` vamos obteniendo las llaves en alguna secuencia y con eso grabamos llave y valor en el archivo.